# Using openMP in fortran and R - where do I set -fopenmp?

Tags: r, openmp

I've read a bit from the Writing R Extensions manual but I can't quite figure this out - where do I put the -fopenmp flag in makevars? I can set

```
PKG_FCFLAGS = -fopenmp
```

which compiles fine. But I'm not sure if I should also be setting it for `PKG_LIBS` and `PKG_CPPFLAGS` ?

When I try for `PKG_LIBS` it gives me an error

```
i686-apple-darwin8-gfortran-4.2: libgomp.spec: No such file or directory
```

But if I just use it in `PKG_FCFLAGS` then even though it compiles fine, when I try to use the routine in R, it says

```
Error in dyn.load("correlate.so") : 
unable to load shared object '/Users/Steven/Documents/PhD/npsR/correlate.so':
dlopen(/Users/Steven/Documents/PhD/npsR/correlate.so, 6): Symbol not found: _GOMP_parallel_end
Referenced from: /Users/Steven/Documents/PhD/npsR/correlate.so
Expected in: dynamic lookup
```

So obviously the gomp library has not been linked correctly. Any ideas?

Cheers.

Comment: It could be linked correctly but it might not be in the `dyld` library path. Check that the path to `libgomp` is present in the value of the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable. Also check that `-fopenmp` is added to the linker flags if GCC is also used as a linker (look for `PKG_LDFLAGS` or similar variable).

Comment: Are there any existing packages that use openmp in Fortran you can copy?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your responses. When I type `echo $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` it comes up with nothing should that be right? Checking the Makeconf file, there is a variable `LDFLAGS` which has the value `-L/usr/local/lib`. This directory has no libgomp, only a libgmp. Could it be that this is an older version of the library? There is no `PKG_LDFLAGS` variable in Makeconf, the closest thing is probably the `LDFLAGS`. Should I add -fopenmp to this? I don't know of any packages using openmp do you? Cheers.

Comment: `libgomp` is usually somewhere deep into the compiler tree (e.g. `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/x86_64/libgomp.a`, the `.spec` file is also there). Looks like no shared library (`.dylib`) version of `libgomp` is provided by Xcode and it is only linked statically, so you don't have to mess with `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that you are using `gfortran` which is not part of Xcode. Where did you get it from?

Comment: Hi I am using the gfortran from here - http://cran.csiro.au/bin/macosx/tools/gfortran-4.2.3.dmg. This was recommended to use since it is part of Rtools. I have found a few libgomp files elsewhere, but not in /usr/local/lib. Should I just use an -I/xxx to where those files are? But why is my gfortran compiler not picking up where they are when I link with -fopenmp??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have solved this issue (though I have opened up another can of worms now...). I'm not sure *exactly* what I did which solved the issue but I'll list what I did do here.

After finding that the fortran program itself would not compile and link with openMP (not counting in R at all) I figured it was something to do with the gfortran installation. So what I did was:

- Uninstalled R
- Uninstalled gfortran
- Downloaded gcc and gfortran from http://r.research.att.com/tools/gcc-42-5666.3-darwin11.pkg
- Installed the updated gcc+gfortran (gfortran v4.2.4)
- Installed R 2.15.1
- Set the line `PATH = /usr/bin:$PATH` in my `.bash_profile`
- Set two lines in Makevars: `PKG_FCFLAGS = -fopenmp` and `PKG_LIBS = -fopenmp`. It seems both of these are necessary.

Then it worked! By the way, this is on OS X 10.7 (Lion).

Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 3):

Luke Tierney's pnmath package http://homepage.stat.uiowa.edu/~luke/R/experimental/ uses OpenMP and has the following in its Makevars:

```
PKG_CFLAGS=-fopenmp
PKG_LIBS=-lgomp
```

and Makevars.win:

```
PKG_CFLAGS=-fopenmp
PKG_LIBS=-mthreads -lgomp -lpthreadGC2
```

You seem to be on a Mac so maybe neither work. But setting `PKG_LIBS=-lgomp` looks critical.

Comment: Thanks for that. Hmm it's odd that its not working when I use this option then. In fact, I'm trying to just compile a fortran program which uses the routine that I am trying to get to work with R. I figured at least if its purely just fortran it would work. But I get `gfortran -fopenmp op.f90 
i686-apple-darwin8-gfortran-4.2: libgomp.spec: No such file or directory`

Comment: Also, the pnmath package uses openmp in C which may have a slightly different linking structure?

Comment: Have you successfully compiled and run any standalone (non-R linking) Fortran with openmp? You should be able to get verbose info from that process to see where all the important bits are coming from. Take R out of the equation...

Comment: Hi, yes I tried that and it didn't work which made me realise that something was wrong with my gfortran installation. I'll post an answer which says what I did. Cheers for your help.

Comment: Just a note, I had to set `-fopenmp` in `PKG_CXXFLAGS` rather than `PKG_CFLAGS`, probably because I already had something defined there and `PKG_CFLAGS` was apparently ignored.

Comment: Well, R is now up from version 2.15-ish to 3.0.2 since this question, and things have changed...